# Twig Syntax Error in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, twig

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Bundle "AdescBundles" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?") in "AdescBundle:Default:index.html.twig"

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 4):

You made a mistake in the bundle name, `AdescBundles` should be `AdescBundle`